# Count all elements with the specific resource ID on the scrollable view

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, android

Here is the question. How can I count all the elements with the resource ID *body_bubble* on a scrollable view ? 
When I use the `driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble")).size()` method, it gets only the elements that are currently in view (visible on the screen).

How can I find all the elements? I know that I can use something like `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView`, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In modern applications to gain performance not all the content is loaded at once. Option I would suggest is.

> Can you scroll to the bottom of the page in the start and then try to find the elements? That way you can be sure that all the elements were loaded.

Comment: It does not work. There still will be visible only those elements that are currently visible on the screen.

Comment: To find all elements you can always use
`driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble"))`
This will give you a list of IWebElements to do whatever you want. Of-course check the locator first because if that is not correct then nothing will work anyways.

Comment: You don't understand. I'm already using this method and it returns only those elements that are currently on the screen (visible). Other elements that will appear only after scrolling up or down I'm not able to get with this method. And that is my question: how can I get them all (even those that are not visible on the screen right now, but will be if you scroll).

Comment: `driver.findElements` will find anything that is present in DOM. Your issue is those elements not being present in DOM, so as per my original suggestion can you first scroll to the bottom of the page? This will make sure your elements are loaded and then you can do `driver.findElements`

Comment: As per my original reply, your suggestion did not work.
It seems that you assume that if something works for Selenium, it will work for Appium also.
In this case you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll Android app screen by 1/3 or 1/4 of full size of screen and use find all element and check there any new changes in screen elements e.g bubble element ID.
continue this as long as there is change in elements appear on scroll.

`driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble"));` store in `Arraylist` and check text, if all duplicate text appear means there is no new text appeared elements are fetched.